# хука the_content

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите как в хук вставить еще доп данные ?

```
add_filter('the_content', 'the_end');
function the_end( $text ){
    return $text . pods_field_display( 'office' );
}
```

Доп поля которые нужно ещё вывести

```
<?php echo pods_field_display( 'step' );  ?>
<?php echo pods_field_display( 'sity_phone' );  ?>
<?php echo pods_field_display( 'office_phone' );  ?>
```

Comment: Можете конкатенировать к `$text . pods_field_display( 'office' );`.

Comment: спасибо, получилось return $text . pods_field_display('dolgnost').pods_field_display('office');